# i use following code for inserting data in sql server which does not add data and also no error?

Tags: c#, sql

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

 SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand();
 com2.Connection = con;
 com2.CommandText = "insert tb_items (item_name, item_unit) values ('" + this.txtitemname.Text + "','" + this.txtitemunit.Text + "')";
 con.Open();

  com2.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Why `ExecuteScalar`? Do you expect any output value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead of `ExecuteScalar`.

(You should also use `using` statements, and use parameterized SQL instead of including user input directly in your SQL statement, but that's another matter. A [*very important*](http://bobby-tables.com) matter, admittedly...)